# Past Simple or Past Perfect with "before" and regular action

Tags: past-tense

"A famous footballer lived in our house before we bought it"

Why is this sentence correct? Is it a regular action in the past?

Why not "had lived"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the past perfect *had lived* is possible there. But English speakers often do not bother to use the past perfect when the temporal relations are clear for other reasons; so *lived* is equally natural.

One effect of the choice is that if you used *had lived*, then you are focussing the sentence on the time when you bought it; if you use *lived* then you are not. In many cases this will not make any difference. But if you go on to say further things without specifying a time, if might make a difference.

> A famous footballer had lived in our house before we bought it. There was a cupboard full of football memorabilia.

suggests that the cupboard was still full when we bought it, because the first sentence established the focus at the time when we bought it.

> A famous footballer lived in our house before we bought it. There was a cupboard full of football memorabilia.

does not have this suggestion: it may be talking about when the footballer lived there.